# Wordpress robots index follow is not included, even though search engine visibility unchecked

Tags: wordpress, seo, search-engine-bots

I already unchecked it:
Settings -> Reading -> Search engine visibility.
So it is in set production now.
But i can see only "max-image-preview:large" in the content.

[image]

I already tried to add in functions php manually:

```
function wp_add_robots_custom( $robots ) {
    $robots['follow'] = true;
    $robots['index'] = true;
    
    return $robots;
}
add_filter( 'wp_robots', 'wp_add_robots_custom' );
```

Therefore i can see that added in my dev localhost.
But it's still not showing in production (online).
Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow and index are the default behaviours, so they are not required.

If noindex and none are not present, then index is assumed.
If nofollow and none are not present, then follow is assumed.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/robots_meta_tag